# Не получается добавить функцию кнопке Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui, unity3d-ui

Я практикую создание меню на Unity. Но у меня не отображается функция в списке функций у кнопки.
Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class azino : MonoBehaviour
{
public void Somefunc()
{
    Debug.Log("123");
}
}
```

А вот то что отображается когда я пытаюсь добавить функцию кнопке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вложите скрипт к необходимому или любому другому объекту на сцене, и этот объект вложите в данное поле, `OnClick` кнопок работает только с объектами со сцены

Comment: Спасибо большое это помогло

Comment: Я рад что смог так быстро решить вашу проблему, я буду рад сильнее если отметите мой ответ как решение если он вам помог